# Which tablet has the best multiuser support in 2023?

Tags: tablet

My small services company has 10 possible users of 3 tablets. The idea is for my technicians to sign-in to the tablet (ideally with their Google Account), bring it with them to a client site, use GPS positioning (the tablet must have LTE), access our website (LTE data, ideally via Google SSO), and not much else. No more than 3 people need a tablet at the same time, and they only really need to use Chrome plus a few apps in the Google ecosystem. I **could** buy all 10 users a tablet, but it's so much more ideal to find a way for 10 users to share 3 tablets securely.

The problem I'm having is that user accounts on tablets like the [Samsung A8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09RQ49B5D) are a horrendous UX, and worse, max out at **6** users. I could have a single user and multiple Google accounts on Chrome, but it appears there's no way to sign **OUT** of an account in Android Chrome, and anyone can switch between Google accounts in Chrome without any authentication.

Not even the [iPad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09G9GLLRN) offers multiple user support out of the box. I couldn't find any reference to limits or workings of multi-user support on the [Google Pixel Slate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083J3T3SV) Tablet, maybe I'll try one and find out the hard way.

How do other people do this? Are there any elegant solutions today for multi-user tablets with LTE?